# Manifest merger Failed : minimum sdkversion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4]

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle, android-api-levels

I just add Firebase in my build.gradle and set it update. After synchronize error shown minsdk 11 cannot lower than 14 declare in libraries. my build.gradle dependencies is below. A suggestion show in Build Gradle message in Android Monitor that use tool:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_core" to force use.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.indiauthoritymarketing.instasave"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "InstaSve 2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.2.2'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And Build Dependencies is below :--

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Where I missing.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, Firebase is distributed as part of Play Services.  Play Services now requires a minimum API level 14 to use it.  So you have to target API level 14 at a minimum.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html

Comment: Updating Minisdk from 11 to 14 in Build Gradle occur error in my XML File as below

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow what you're saying.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. After Updating minsdk from 11 to 14 solve my issue. Thanks Again.